# How check if length value of array keys is bigger then 1

Tags: php, arrays

With array map i can get length of string inside array:

```
$array[] = "1";
$array[] = "22";
$array[] = "333";
$array[] = "4444";
$len = array_map("strlen", $array);
print_r($len);//Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 )
```

Now i need check if the value is bigger then 1, how the way to do that?

Comment: Cast it to an int?

Comment: Pls, can say what is wrong to made my question better?

Comment: Do you mean the value in the array is > 1, or the length of the value in the array is > 1?

Comment: tks for atention @Nick, i need know the value, becouse he is the number of length, but if have other way to check if length is > 1 without count length before is welcome too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if the length of the value is greater than 1, this will work:

```
$lengt1 = array_map(function ($v) { return strlen($v) > 1; }, $array);
foreach ($lengt1 as $key => $val) {
    echo "\$lengt1[$key] = " . ($val ? 'true' : 'false') . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
$lengt1[0] = false
$lengt1[1] = true
$lengt1[2] = true
$lengt1[3] = true
```

If you need to know if the value is > 1, then this will work:

```
$vgt1 = array_map(function ($v) { return (int)$v > 1; }, $array);
foreach ($vgt1 as $key => $val) {
    echo "\$vgt1[$key] = " . ($val ? 'true' : 'false') . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
$vgt1[0] = false
$vgt1[1] = true
$vgt1[2] = true
$vgt1[3] = true
```

Comment: tks again, perfect here!